# express static hosting image doesn't work for IP address 192.168.x.x

Tags: node.js, express

It's such a weird issue:

```
import express from 'express';

const app1 = express();
app1.use('/', express.static('/Users/tyler.liu/Desktop', {dotfiles: 'allow'}));

app1.listen(8002, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('http://192.168.1.236:8002/icon.png');
});
```

192.168.1.236 is my laptop's IP address.

When I try to access http://192.168.1.236:8002/icon.png in Chrome browser:

[image]

Safari browser:

[image]

It works in both browser if I access http://127.0.0.1:8002/icon.png

it works too if I try to access a text file: http://192.168.1.236:8002/temp.txt

So the issue can be reproduced if:

1. the file is image instead of text
2. you try to access it by a private address such as 192.168.x.x instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I think it might have something to do with my local network. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the root cause but it must have something to do with express.

I tried

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8090
```

and it workd.

I tried [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) and it also worked.

So for now the workaround is: do NOT use express.js